# How to update each element in a List in Java 8 using Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a List defined as follows:

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add(1); 
list1.add(2);
```

How can I increment each element of the List by one (i.e. end up with a List `[2,3]`) using Java 8's Stream API without creating new List?

Comment: Why do you not want to create a new list?

Comment: @ifly6 for example, you may have a method which is expected to work via side-effects.

Comment: Simple, use `.map()` for any manipulation. See @bentaye answer

Comment: DownVoted :  lack of research

Comment: UpVoted: good question

Answer (score 20):

When you create a `Stream` from the `List`, you are not allowed to modify the source `List` from the `Stream` as specified in the [“Non-interference” section of the package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference). Not obeying this constraint can result in a `ConcurrentModificationException` or, even worse, a corrupted data structure without getting an exception.

The only solution to directly manipulate the list using a Java Stream, is to create a Stream not iterating over the list itself, i.e. a stream iterating over the indices like

```
IntStream.range(0, list1.size()).forEach(ix -> list1.set(ix, list1.get(ix)+1));
```

<sup>like in [Eran’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48110643/2711488)</sup>

But it’s not necessary to use a `Stream` here. The goal can be achieved as simple as

```
list1.replaceAll(i -> i + 1);
```

This is [a new `List` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) introduced in Java 8, also allowing to smoothly use a lambda expression. Besides that, there are also the probably well-known [`Iterable.forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-), the nice [`Collection.removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-), and the in-place [`List.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) method, to name other new Collection operations not involving the Stream API. Also, the [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/Map.html) interface got several new methods worth knowing.

See also “[New and Enhanced APIs That Take Advantage of Lambda Expressions and Streams in Java SE 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/lambda_api_jdk8.html)” from the official documentation.

Answer (score 3):

[Holger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48110767/7294647) is just about perfect.  However, if you're concerned with integer overflow, then you can use another utility method that was released in Java 8: [`Math#incrementExact`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#incrementExact-int-).  This will throw an `ArithmeticException` if the result overflows an `int`.  A method reference can be used for this as well, as seen below:

```
list1.replaceAll(Math::incrementExact);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the indices via an `IntStream` combined with `forEach`:

```
IntStream.range(0,list1.size()).forEach(i->list1.set(i,list1.get(i)+1));
```

However, this is not much different than a normal for loop, and probably less readable.

Answer (score 0):

reassign the result to `list1`:

```
list1 = list1.stream().map(i -> i+1).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: From the OP **"without creating new List"**. You are creating a new List.

Comment: To be fair, it is not clear if he means new list like a `new variable` or `new object`.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static Function<Map<String, LinkedList<Long>>, Map<String, LinkedList<Long>>> applyDiscount = (

            objectOfMAp) -> {


        objectOfMAp.values().forEach(listfLong -> {


            LongStream.range(0, ((LinkedList<Long>) listfLong).size()).forEach(index -> {

                Integer position = (int) index;

                Double l = listfLong.get(position) - (10.0 / 100 * listfLong.get(position));

                listfLong.set(position, l.longValue());

            });

        });

        return objectOfMAp;

    };
```